# Issue with iOS Web App Splash Screen

Tags: html, ios

I've been having an issue with my website using the iOS Web App meta information. I've been able to get it to work for every device, except the Retina iPad in Landscape. For reasons I can't understand, it's only showing the splash image in the bottom left corner, like it's using the non-Retina image, but I don't know why. It works for the portrait orientation.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    <!-- Do NOT use width=device width because it will letterbox viewport on iPhone 5... thanks for making it easy Apple. -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

    <!-- iPhone 4 Retina -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/iphone4.jpg">
    <!-- iPhone 5 Retina -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/iphone5.jpg">

    <!-- iPad Retina Portrait -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipadretinaport.jpg">
    <!-- iPad Retina Landscape -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipadretina.jpg">        

    <!-- iPad Non-Retina Portrait -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipadport.jpg">
    <!-- iPad Non-Retina Landscape -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipad.jpg">
```

The website is active at www.reckless-intent.com if you want to see it running for yourself. I've tried clearing my cache and cookies. I don't have another iPad I can test it on to see if it's isolated.

Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it :)

[image: Image of error on Retina iPad]

Comment: [That's](http://imgur.com/NbBJtAi) how it looks like when I first open the page. I don't see a splash screen ...

Comment: Have you been able to try it in portrait mode?

Comment: [Same result](http://imgur.com/et3GzdP) ... No splash screen ... sorry ;(

Comment: btw: same result on iPhone 5 ...

Comment: That's so odd... it's working fine on my iPhone 5.

Comment: Just tried it on an old iPhone 4, still working for me.

Comment: Hmm ... Dunno why that might happen, but I just entered the URL from your question and hit enter ... And then I landed on the start page - No splash screen

Comment: Oh, you need to touch the Action button, then "Add to Home Screen". Launch it from there, and it should have the splash screen?

Comment: It's working in [portrait mode](http://imgur.com/YoLCmhp), but not in landscape :/ Same result as yours

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird.

Comment: I'm not sure if the viewport of the retina ipad is any different than the regular ipad. That being said, try using 768px instead of 1536.

Comment: Neat, that worked! Thank you very much! =D If you post it as the Answer, I'll mark it for you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user Markus stated in the comments thread above, the solution to my problem was the viewport, it should have been 768px instead of 1536px.

The code below is now running perfectly fine on iPhone 4, 5, and the iPad and iPad Retina.

```
    <!-- iPhone 4 Retina -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/iphone4.jpg">

    <!-- iPhone 5 Retina -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/iphone5.jpg">

    <!-- iPad (portrait) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipad.jpg">

    <!-- iPad (landscape) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipadport.jpg">

    <!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipadretinaport.jpg">

    <!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="http://www.reckless-intent.com/assets/images/ios/ipadretina.jpg">
```

Comment: Dumb question, but will this work for regular sites showing in Safari iOS?

Comment: No, it won't work on any browser. This only works on webapps added to the homeScreen on iOs

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your first comment. The above method will only work in iOS, however there are other attributes you can add for Windows 8 and Windows Phone tiles. Here's the method for Windows Phone: 

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/19/creating-a-custom-tile-to-link-to-your-website.aspx

The Windows 8 method is similar, I believe. Best to look it up on SO or MSDN :) Hope it helped!